# C# Regular Expression - Something or Nothing

Tags: c#, regex

I have two types of possible lines to get information from:

```
<td class="forecast">106.2%</td>
```

or

```
<td class="forecast"></td>
```

And I want to get what is inside, it can be something, like a number, or it can be exactly nothing, not even a white space.

I have the following piece of regular expression:

```
<td class=\"forecast\">\\s*(.+?)\\s*</td>
```

It works, when there is content inside the HTML cell, but if there is nothing, it gets the following part of the HTML code.

Does someone knows how to solve this?

Comment: Read the classical response http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/932418 and the solution https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

Comment: The `(.+?)` becomes slightly greedy until if finds something before a closing td.

Comment: plus one for good question, okay, go for voting now..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just change the `(.+?)` to `(.*?)`.

- `+` = One or More
- `*` = Zero or More

Added: [Regexr](http://regexr.com/3bcdf)

Comment: Working now.
Newbie problems... Thanks so much.

Comment: @Nuno, I'm glad to help. Feel free to Upvote/Accept :)

Comment: I was trying to click on the upper arrow, it says I must have some reputation points first, but now I see I can click also in the check below the down arrow, it told me I can do it in 3 minutes :)